Visual Studio Code, The extension host terminated unexpectedly
I have been getting this error non-stop
I disabled all of my extension, and it did nothing even uninstall VS Code completely with all the data and didn't do anything:

I also tried the "Extension Bisect" utility, but it didn't find anything.
My extensions were C++ and Java extension package and code runner and GitHub themes
